# go get ./... refuses to download gopkg.in/yaml.v2

Tags: go

I'm just "getting" all required libraries by using `go get ./...` and go-get happily downloads all libs which are imported directly from github.com, however I get the error:

```
src/github.com/urfave/cli/altsrc/yaml_file_loader.go:17:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" in any of:
    /home/ci/.jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/Go_1.6/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/ci/.jenkins/jobs/BlenderRender-Client/workspace/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from $GOPATH)
```

Sure, I could `go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2` and it would work, however I'm setting up a CI server to automatically compile my project and I'd rather have `go get ./...` just download *everything* and not complain about gopkg.in-packets since I don't want to reconfigure my CI server every time some requirement changes.

Is there a way to tell `go get ./...` that it's fine to download `gopkg.in` packets?

Comment: I never saw anyone download packages this way. I'm seeing a problem here. When one of your deps update a version your project can break because version incompatibility. Did you take a look at vendoring?

Comment: Yeah I did take a look, but I didn't use it yet. It feels overwhelming because there are so many different applications for vendoring and I was used to just use `go get`. Which one of the many vendoring apps do you recommend?

Comment: I'm using [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have issues with get, try `go get -v gopkg.in/yaml.v2` and you'll face an error if you have git <=1.7.1

Just upgrade your git client, and problem fixed

You can also solve this by cloning the yaml.v2 repo into :
`/home/ci/.jenkins/jobs/BlenderRender-Client/workspace/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2`

run a `git clone https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml.git /home/ci/.jenkins/jobs/BlenderRender-Client/workspace/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2`

Comment: this answer help me find the solution, in my case a build inside Docker was failing, I updated my golang version from `FROM golang:1.10-alpine3.8 as builder` to `FROM golang:1.12.5-alpine3.9 as builder`